# Can I safely cast to a function returning void?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion, function-pointers

Casting between function types which take different arguments or return different types is not safe for obvious reasons.

What isn't obvious (to me) is whether it should be safe to cast to a function pointer type where the return type is void (and the argument types are the same).

Is there a mechanism to safely cast for instance `int (*)()` to `void (*)()`? `static_cast` fails here. `reinterpret_cast` works, but is unsafe.

Is there a safe way?

`std::function<void()>(funcReturningInt)` seems to pull off the trick, but I can't seem to peer through it's labyrinth implementation to see how.

Comment: This is still undefined behavior. `std::function` solves it by calling the function with its original `int` return value, and then throwing the `int` away. E.g. `void operator() { (*pointer_to_function_returning_int)(); }` - it calls the function returning int and just throws the int away. This is different from casting to a function returning void and then calling with the wrong function prototype. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: @RaymondChen it sounds like what you're saying belongs as an answer rather than comment. However, `std::function<void()>(&funcReturningInt)`, must store funcReturning int as a generic type. I'll edit my question to be clearer about std::function.

Comment: `std::function` doesn't store a function pointer. Note that it can wrap any callable - e.g. a class with `operator()` - not just a plain function. Since it doesn't store a function pointer, it has no need to cast to one, either.

Comment: Even if the casting works, calling it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @P.W , hence the next phrase *"but is unsafe"*...

Comment: @Catskul: I think it is unsafe even by means other than `reinterpret_cast` which you have referred to.

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? What are you really trying to achieve, that you hope this cast will get you closer to? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @P.W ... which is why I'm asking *"Is there a safe way?"*...

Comment: @Catskul: Safe way to cast: Yes. (the title of the question). Safe way to use after it is casted: No.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have a problem that I have answer to, but it caused me to think about question about a part of casting that I don't fully understand. Hence I'm asking  about the fundamental problem rather than the specific case that caused me to ask it.

Comment: @p.w if you think that's true, make an answer and explain why you know this instead commenting.

Comment: @Catskul: I have been trying to find a reference from the C++ standard for this but could not. The only references I could find are part of the explanation of different casts. Unfortunately, it is not clearly spelled out in C++ as it is in the C standard. In C we know for sure that this is unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no safe casts.

The answer according to the c++ standard is given by another answer, here I want to explain practically why that's so.

There are different ways to handle return values, C/C++ doesn't define or restrict how to handle return values. They are defined inside ABI.

There are several calling conventions defined inside X86 ABI, like `cdecl`, `stdcall` or `thiscall`. Different calling conventions handle return values differently, the most relevant fact here is that where are return values stored.

If return values are stored inside the stack, caller must adjust the stack pointer after retrieving the return values. In this case if you converted the return values to void, then the caller won't be able to adjust the stack pointer, in general case the stack is corrupted, which will mostly lead to a crash.

If return values are stored inside registers, caller may assume that these registers haven't been modified when calling a function returning void, but if it isn't, these registers may be modified by callee. The disagreement may also cause a crash.

If you insist on using the type cast, just make sure you choose the correct calling convention that the return values doesn't affect.

Answer (score 2):

Per the standard, there are no safe casts

> **[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6** A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer of a different type. [ *Note:* The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type (11.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined. *—end note* ] Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP is aware of this.

Comment: @P.W In one comment, the OP asked for proof that they can cast but can't call through the result of the cast. This paragraph from the standard states exactly that.

Comment: So this undefined behavior is applicable for any means and not just in the context of `reinterpret_cast`? If that is the case, this is an answer.

Comment: @P.W All other casts either would be ill-formed (e.g. `static_cast`) or are defined in terms of `reinterpret_cast` (e.g. C-style cast). To demonstrate this, one would need to quote a good chunk of **[expr]**, which the margins of this post are too small to contain. We leave the research into various types of casts as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out a cast is not safe. And `std::function` is unnecessary. If you want to pass a function to something expecting a pointer to a void function and ignore the return result you can easily do that with a lambda:

```
int foo();

auto gimme_gimme_a_function_after_midnight(void (*f)() )
{
    f();
}

auto test()
{
    gimme_gimme_a_function_after_midnight([]() { foo(); });
}
```

The lambda just calls the function and ignores the returned value. And because it has no capture it can implicitly cast to a function pointer.

If the function has parameters that's easy to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness the way that std::function does it is by templated constructor. The templated constructor effectively creates a static signature adapter function for each signature type that is requested for storage, and keeps what amounts to a void pointer to the stored function and a function pointer to the adapter function.

At call time it invokes the adapter function with the void pointer and re-casts it back to the original type.